# Can't Connect to Samba Drive Using OS X Lion

Tags: macos, network, smb

I've come across [many](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3196311) [threads](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3208098) on Apple, but haven't found a solution that works for me. I understand that the Samba has been removed from OS X, and Apple has developed their own version. I remember trying connecting to the Samba drive when I first upgraded to Lion, and it didn't work so I gave up. But now I need it. Back in Snow Leopard, I used to write `smb://URL/username`. I didn't have to enter an IP address, but rather a URL to the network drive followed by my username, and it used to work perfectly. It's a URL because this network drive is hosted on campus at my university. I now receive the following error:

`Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator.`

As far as I know, nothing has changed on this network drive side. I am able to mount this drive on the Windows computer easily.

In the Console, I get the following error, which is the same if I try to mount the network drive through terminal:

`Key 'smb_neg' defined before section`

Not sure what that means.

Anybody know an appropriate solution? What about [SMBUp](http://eduo.info/apps/smbup)? Is it safe to install and remove?

Answer (score 2):

Actually Apple has *added* a new implementation of SMB as it is now the default filing protocol for file sharing (actually SMB2)

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57588593-263/os-x-mavericks-switches-to-smb2-networking/

While I don't recognize the error you are getting, try replacing SMB in your connection string with CIFS. EG:

cifs://server/share

That forces Mavericks to go back to the original SMB protocol.

However the fact that this was not working under Lion may indicate an issue of some sort (corrupt file, malware, etc.) with your system. If you have a spare bootable drive you might want to install a fresh copy of Mavericks and boot from that to see if your issue goes away,

Comment: I already tried `cifs://server/share`. It still displays those messages. No idea why. I have a MacBook from 2007 so the latest OS X I can run is Lion, which was freshly installed few months ago.

Comment: Sorry I musta had a brain fart and assumed you were on Mavericks. If it is a fresh install of Lion it SHOULD work. you might want to find the last COMBO update to Lion. Download it and apply. Oftentimes applying a combo update again will fix odd issues like this.